# Polkit authentication dialog locks focus

Tags: policykit, window-management

I'm using XFCE as desktop manager with XFWM as the window manager. Whenever an application uses polkit (or at least that's what I think it is) for authentication, the password dialog locks focus, so that access to any other window is prevented.[image]
Is this dialog created by polkit? How can I stop it from blocking access to the entire desktop?